# Single authentication for applcations on different Jboss servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss

I am working in a javaEE project which is being running on JBOSS application server, the scenario is such that I have two applications say App1.ear and App2.ear which will be deployed at two different server Jboss1 and Jboss2 and their domain will be same as jboss1.xyz.com and jboss2.xyz.com. Now the problem is that if user login through App1 and then only he should be able to access App2, so authentication will be only once at the App1. I have gone through the single sign valve on jboss but this solution is not working for me, Please suggest any good solution for this situation as the application should be very secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to store a cookie with a token, and have a persistant storage shared between the apps which stores info about these tokens. So when the user makes a switch, App2 can get the cookie and check in the storage whether its valid or not. If it is, then the user will be permitted to use App2.

You will have to maintain the storage though, like cleaning up tokens when the users log out, or session times out.

Comment: thanks for your reply!! i will try to implement as suggested by you but being a secured application i don't to take risk of session stealing which can be a case in your solution or might be i am lacking in knowledge it will be better if you can put some thought on security of such implementation.